# Read a property of a array with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

This is the Schema:

```
var userschema = new mongoose.Schema({

   user: String,
   pass: String,
   imagen: [{ 

              title: String,
              author: String,
              description: String,
              index: Number,
              path: String,

           }]

});
```

I'm trying with 'foomodel.find', to find inside the imagen array of the Schema, a element with an specific property, I mean:

```
usermodel.find({ user: foo, 'imagen.index': 1 }, function (err, imagen){

        if(err) throw err;

        console.log(imagen);

});
```

In the console, I received this `[]`, when I want to received the properties of the imagen array's element, that has the index as one. I checked it exist. Any solution...?

Thank's advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use [*$elementMatch*](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/read/):

```
usermodel.find({ user: foo, "imagen": {"$elemMatch":{"index": 1 }}, 
    function (err, imagen){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(imagen);
});
```